# How can I automatically get the Apple (Mac) mail app to display the sender's email rather than their account name?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I was wondering if there was any way for me to get the standard Mac email client to display the sender's full email rather than the account name? Some of my email adresses are susceptible to phishing and it is slightly annoying to constantly have to click on the dropdown bar for every email to check.
[How the email sender is currently displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCRgE.png)

Note:
According to this (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251434424) apple discussion, you can't change the "at a glance" settings to show it, but is there any workaround for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know of a way to add this to the list of messages, you can have it displayed automatically when you open the message by using custom header display in the display pane of preferences.

See the section on "Show message headers" at:
https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/change-viewing-settings-cpmlprefview/mac

Adding "Return-Path" in a custom header leaves the sender/subject/to as usually displayed, then shows the email address.  Thanks to your question, I've changed my setup.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely good enough for me. The Mail app is only so customizable but this will work.